# Interval between transactions with the same Transaction ID

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

We use the Google Analytics [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en) to send offline transactions to Google Analytics. Sometimes we need to send two or more transaction with the same [ID](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ti) (and positive revenue). It works properly when we send transactions (with the same ID) in some days. However when we send two transactions (with the same ID) on interval of 1-2 minutes only one of them is considered in Analytics and another is ignored.

Is there any minimum interval between sending transaction with the same ID?

**Code from comment:**

```
$curl=curl_init(http://google-analytics.com/collect'); 
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true); 
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'v=1'.'&ni=1'.'&tid='.$track_id.'&cid='.$client_id . '&t=transaction'.'&ti='.$transaction_id.'&tr='.$revenue); 
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Any chance you can come up with a simple script that can show this?   Give me a couple of your requests so we can see the problem.

Comment: I have no idea and that's a good question, but since the minimum granularity in the GA reports is in minutes it might be that multiple transactions within the same minute are ignored.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I am wondering if its a session issue.   Need to test this. agreed really good question

Comment: We use simple PHP code for sending:  `code $curl=curl_init(http://google-analytics.com/debug/collect');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'v=1'.'&ni=1'.'&tid='.$track_id.'&cid='.$client_id . $data);
curl_exec($curl);`

Comment: @Eike Pierstorff Transactions (with the same ID) were sent in different minutes. So the granularity constraint is satisfied.

Comment: Um just wondering but you know that debug/collect wont actually send anything right?

Comment: Yes. It's just misprint. Really we use http://google-analytics.com/collect